# how to modify date format in javascript (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a date format like **2015-12-07T02:45:00.000Z** but want to convert it to like **Nove 12 , 2015 4:30 PM** or **3 minuts** ago accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). And use 
`moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')` to convert to your format or 
`moment().startOf('hour').fromNow()` to print out relative time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? It has relative conversions which seem to be what you are looking for.